# Connect to ropsten network from Node.js

Tags: metamask, nodejs, ropsten

I need to connect to Ropsten network from my Node.js backend .
I need to read logs and extract data from them and listen to changes in the network for my contract.
The problem is that i don't know how to input credentials of the account that's going to read it (address and private key  )

```
 if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

This is my code from frontend . I'm using metamask and it's getting me the current provider perfectly. 
But when changing to Node.js , there's no provider of course (Metamask in my case ) .

**So the question is :** 
How to input Ropsten network instead of "http://localhost:8545" which refers to a private network and how can i input the account's address and secret key ? 
Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a ropsten node, either in remote or in local, as you would do for a real Ethereum node.

Simplest answer I can give you for testing is to use the [infura.io](https://infura.io/) node. Subscribe to the service and they will send you by mail an url of the form `https://ropsten.infura.io/API_KEY`. Just input the url in your code like this:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/API_KEY"))
```

Comment: hi can you please look into https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57524/cannot-connect-to-any-ethereum-networks-using-api-key I followed your method but cannot connect